# Failing to access a folder by InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

I'm trying to access a created folder by `FileInputStream`, but Tomcat   returned an exception.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:(directoy path) access denied.
```

Here's the code which creates the folder.

```
String dirname = "Myfolder";
File dir = new File( dirname );
dir.mkdirs();
```

My problem is that I cannot access this folder by InputStream.

Comment: "access denied" - check folder permissions and verify the user running your process can access the folder ...

Comment: its not problem of permission

Comment: How do you create your FileInputStream ?

Comment: IOUtils.copy( new FileInputStream(dir), os );

Answer (score 5):

You can't access a directory with `FileInputStream`. You can read a file *in* the directory, or you can list the contents of the directory with e.g. `new File(directory).listFiles()`.

Answer (score 0):

Print out absolute path of this directory and make sure you are in the right place.

```
log.debug(">>> " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
```

And then check if user running JVM has access to that directory or even if it exists.

Comment: Hi,is there anyone knows how to create a folder in the server memory, and i want to this folder be managed by the JVM.
    i dont want to store the folder in the system. 
    here's what ive used to create a folder in the system:
    String dirname = "Myfolder";
    File dir = new File( dirname );
    dir.mkdirs();
    but i dont want this i want to create the folder in the server memory.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem can help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a directory with `FileInputStream`. To copy a directory, you can use the `Files.copy(Path, Path, CopyOption...)` method from JDK7:

```
String dirname = "Myfolder";
File dir = new File(dirname);
dir.mkdirs();
// ...
Files.copy(dir.toPath(), Paths.get("/target"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

See this page from the Java Tutorial for more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html